# Find the parent Dialog of a Button

Tags: android, dialog

I have an alert dialog which contains a button.  The button is defined in some XML and the layout is set using Dialog.setContentView().

The button has a listener class and I want to know how, if at all, I can access the dialog from the onClick(View v) method.

The reason for this is simply that I want to be able to dismiss the dialog - so if there's an easier/better way to do this then that would be useful to know!

Answer (score 1):

Simple solution using the `onCreateDialog()` method from the `Activity` class:

```
// member variable
Dialog mDialog;

protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
    Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);
    switch (id) {
        case DELETE_ALL_DIALOG:
            builder.setCancelable(false);
            builder.setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    //do what you want
                }
            });
            builder.setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    dismissDialog(DELETE_ALL_DIALOG); // thats what you are looking for
                }
            });
            builder.setMessage(R.string.delete_all_bookmarks_question);
            mDialog = builder.create();
            mDialog.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
            return mDialog;
        default:
            return super.onCreateDialog(id);
    }
}
```

Comment: This works but seems like unnecessary logic when really the dialog should be extracted out as a custom class if you ask me :)

Answer (score 0):

Create a custom dialog class and define the button in there. Something like:

```
public class CustomizeDialog extends Dialog implements OnClickListener {
    Button okButton;

    public CustomizeDialog(Context context) {
        super(context);
        /** 'Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE' - Used to hide the title */
        requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
        /** Design the dialog in main.xml file */
        setContentView(R.layout.main);
        okButton = (Button) findViewById(R.id.OkButton);
        okButton.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        /** When OK Button is clicked, dismiss the dialog */
        if (v == okButton)
            dismiss();
    }
```

Comment: I should point out that my listener is currently a seperate Class and not an inner one

Comment: Then you'd have to pass a reference as you have done. Have you considered using the AlertDialog.Builder and maybe using setNegativeButton(CharSequence text, DialogInterface.OnClickListener listener)

Answer (score 0):

For now I've simply passed a reference to the dialog into the listener class and then called dismiss() at the appropriate time.

This doesn't seem like the best way - is there a better one?

Creating a custom dialog seems unnecessary to me... It doesn't need anything out of the ordinary.

Comment: Looks like that is the best way if you don't want to encapsulate the dialog in a separate class. Would have to be that or a global dialog in the activity class